# How to set spark-submit number of retries if you're not using yarn, but spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to set retry to 3 for spark-submit jobs. But, I'm not using the yarn cluster.

I understand in Yarn we can use `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=3`.

What's the equivalent for this if I'm using Spark cluster instead of yarn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark.excludeOnFailure.task.maxTaskAttemptsPerExecutor
spark.excludeOnFailure.task.maxTaskAttemptsPerNode

Comment: I will try that.